# Spawning vim from a node git hook

Tags: node.js, git, vim, coffeescript, githooks

I've got a project purely in coffeescript, with git hooks for deployment also written in cs. I don't really want to break away from the language just to use bash for a quick commit message formatter, but I've got a problem spawning vim from the commit-msg hook.

I've seen [here](https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why) that when piping to vim, the stdio is not necessarily set correctly to the tty streams. I get how that could cause a problem, but I don't exactly know how to get vim to load correctly using nodes spawn command. At the moment I have...

```
vim = (require 'child_process').spawn('vim', [file], stdio: 'inherit')
vim.on 'exit', (err) ->
  console.log "Exited! [#{err}]"
  cb?()
```

...which works fine to spawn a vim process that can r/w from the parents stdio, but when I use this in the hook things go wrong. Vim states that the stdio is not from terminal, and then once opened typing causes escape characters to pop up all over the place. Backspace for example, will produce `^?`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, got this working.

It transpires that git suspends the normal stdin handle when running git hooks. I can only assume this is due to most hooks having arguments passed by stdin, but either way it means that when I was calling vim and asking it to inherit from our parent process stdio, vim received `/dev/null` as the stdin stream.

Vim actually performs ioctl operations on stdin and these fail with the `/dev/null` handle. The solution was to spawn vim with a stdin pointing directly at the keyboard, or `/dev/tty`. This allows for correct vim interaction, and can be run directly from the githook.

Full solution is gisted [here](https://gist.github.com/LawrenceJones/81a3865659351f96502f), but in summary...

```
ttyFd   = fs.openSync '/dev/tty', 'r'

spawnVim = (file, cb) ->
  vim = (require 'child_process').spawn('vim', [file], customFds: [ttyFd,1,2])
  vim.on 'exit', cb
```

Comment: I had to tweak that a bit to get it working. `const keyboardStream = fs.openSync('/dev/tty', 'r'); const editor = childProcess.spawn(process.env.EDITOR, ['/tmp/stuff'], { stdio: [keyboardStream, 1, 2] });`

These docs helped https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio